# How to fix background image flickering upon scrolling

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, blogger

So the background image is resizing and  busting out of viewport when 'site url' portion moves up and down. The problem is occurring in Chrome Android. Here is a video link of the problem.

https://youtube.com/watch?v=HsxC3Pa1JC4

And I am just using basic styling for image.

```css
body {
  background-image: url('imgurl');
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
}
```

I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know whats the issue exactly.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 the problem is when the address bar moves up the background image resizes and expands with a jump. Putting it in codepen or snippet doesn't show any problem.

Comment: Managed to get YouTube. The background moving is unsurprising, but the page content moving _does_ seem weird to me: have you got any `@media` queries involving the viewport height?

Comment: If a codepen or snippet don't show any problem, does a blank page with minimal HTML and the CSS you've provided show the problem? If not, please create a [mcve] (that page should give instructions) and explain how to reproduce the issue. It doesn't _have_ to be as a Stack Snippet. (Make sure to include the image dimensions.)